# Implement variable learning rate Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I want to implement a Cyclic Learning Rate, as opposed to AdamOptimizer or any other form of SGD for example.
So the part I want to introduce here is a "Cyclic Learning Rate", with the function `get_triangular_lr`. The function is shown below:

```
def get_triangular_lr(iteration, stepsize, base_lr, max_lr):
    """Given the inputs, calculates the lr that should be applicable for 
       this iteration"""
    scale_fn = lambda x: 1/(2.**(x-1))
    cycle = math.floor(1 + iteration/(2  * stepsize))
    x = abs(iteration/stepsize - 2 * cycle + 1)
    lr = base_lr + (max_lr - base_lr) * max(0, (1-x)) *scale_fn(cycle)
    lr = tf.convert_to_tensor(lr)

    return lr
```

Below, the code is shown for using this in the actual Inception ResNet V2 model, my aim is to replace `tf_train_exponential_decay` with the Cyclic LR, which itself increases and decreases learning rate per step taken.

```
      iteration_step = 0 #(is increased every global_step)
      lr1 = get_triangular_lr(iteration_step, stepsize, base_lr, max_lr)


    #Define your exponentially decaying learning rate
#         lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(
#             learning_rate = initial_learning_rate,
#             global_step = global_step,
#             decay_steps = decay_steps,
#             decay_rate = learning_rate_decay_factor,
#             staircase = True)

    #Now we can define the optimizer that takes on the learning rate

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = lr1)

    #Create the train_op.
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)
```

However, when I run the code above (by running the complete training model), the learning rate never gets increased by using that function. It only starts at `0.0001`, and every global_step taken it uses this value, while it should be increasing every global step (with the new value calculated by `get_triangular_lr`. I think it requires some kind of for-loop, but I can't figure out how exactly to implement it.

```
    #Now we need to create a training step function that runs both the 
    #train_op, metrics_op and updates the global_step concurrently.

    def train_step(sess, train_op, global_step):
        '''
        Simply runs a session for the three arguments provided and gives a 
     logging on the time elapsed for each global step
        '''
        #Check the time for each sess run
        start_time = time.time()
        total_loss, global_step_count, _ = sess.run([train_op, global_step, 
        metrics_op])
        time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time

        #Run the logging to print some results
        logging.info('global step %s: loss: %.4f (%.2f sec/step)', 
        global_step_count, total_loss, time_elapsed)

        return total_loss, global_step_count
```

When I change the input of `train_op` to `total_loss, lr1` it gives me an AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'compute_gradients', and thus the model does not run at all.

**EDIT: Have not yet found solution yet, but managed to use py.func, but now the next error occurs:**

So I created `triangular_tf`, which uses `tf.py_func` to load the function, as follows:

```
triangular_tf = tf.py_func(get_triangular_lr, [iteration, stepsize, base_lr, max_lr], [tf.float64])
```

The only issue is, when I now pass `triangular_tf` to `optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = triangular_tf) the following error occurs:

`ValueError: cannot add op with name <my weights variable name>/Adam as that name is already used`

Not sure whether I still need the AdamOptimizer in this process, but I just simply need a way to adjust learning rate every step.

Comment: You're first attempt seems to be a miscomprehension of the "define then run" design of Tensorflow. You should try to wrap your `get_triangular_lr` function in a [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), or rewrite it using only tensorflow ops. I'll see if I can spend more time on this question later on.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into the `tf.py_func` now. Would be great though if you would see an opportunity later on to help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Managed to solve it yesterday, I wrote my own .py module based on tf.train.exponential_decay, with py_func, which hereafter allowed me to reuse `global_step`, and thus make sure the `learning_rate` was adapted after each step. Thanks for the useful suggestion!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't manage to take the time to help you more. Glad you've figured a way to resolve the problem though!

Comment: You're encouraged to write an answer to your own question if you have found a way to solve the problem. That way future readers that stumble upon the same difficulty can benefit from this.